# Работа с NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Пишу клиентское приложение для работы с сервером.
Приложение посылает на сервер GET-запрос и получает полный список пользователей в виде xml-файла, парсит его и отображает на экране устройства.
 
Проблемы с парсингом XML. Файл по всей видимости загружается, однако приложение не запускает парсинг.

UPD: Парсинг не происходит нормально по причине того, что свойство NSMutable currentString не работает - в него ничего не складируется. Дебаг пишет:

> variable is not CFString

Как бороться с проблемой?

Участки кода отвечающие за это:

```
//Объявление свойства currentString:

NSMutableString *currentString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentString;

//Парсинг:

 NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://0.0.0.0:3000/objs.xml"];
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSMutableURLRequest *requestXML = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl];
 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestXML returningResponse:nil error:&error];
 NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
 NSLog(@"XML is downloaded.");
 self.currentString = [NSMutableString string]; //Никакой реакции, "variable is not CFString", дальнейшее обращение к свойству также игнорируется.
 [xmlParser parse];

#pragma mark NSXMLParser Parsing Callbacks

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"Started");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"obj"]) {
        self.currentUser = [[[UserInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"Start parsing");
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"id"]) {
        [currentString setString:@""];
        storingCharacters = YES;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"obj"]) {
        [self addUserToUserList];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        currentUser.userName = currentString;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"]) {
        currentUser.ID = [currentString intValue];
    } 
    storingCharacters = NO;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (storingCharacters) [currentString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"Error!");
}
```

Comment: что-то не могу понять в чем ошибка, не хватает всего кода и ручной отладки... =\

Если разберетесь в чем проблема сами, то распишите что не так было =)

Comment: Попробуйте по-простому:
замените инициализацию `self.currentString = [NSMutableString string];`
на `currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`

Comment: @VioLet, да он сразу заретейнится в сеттере

Comment: @1101_debian, да, наверное я неправ.  
Привычка просто, не доверяю autorelease, если дело касается переноса объектов между методами.

Comment: Я первым делом пробовал так объявлять, не помогает - оно видимо объявляется и уже "variable is not CFString". Надо будет разобраться, есть подозрение что это вообще какой-то глюк xcode, т.к. аналогичные контрукции работают в других проектах (по отдельности).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед этой строкой

```
[xmlParser parse];
```

добавьте

```
xmlParser.delegate = self;
```

Ваш парсер начинает своб работу, но не знает кому сообщить о том что он что-то распарсил.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно заработало, но я тут столкнулся ещё с одной проблемой - парсинг всё равно не идёт как надо - объект NSMutableString currentString отказывается принимать какие либо-значения, в дебаге пишет - "variable is not CFString". Вы не могли бы помочь советом и в данной ситуации?

Comment: А как объявлено свойство currentString?

Comment: Код:

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentString; 

Ну и далее в `@synthesize`, ясно дело.

Comment: Хм... а попробуйте везде обращаться к строке через self. И в какой строке валится, кстати?

Comment: Обновил шапку.